# PyCharm freezes after executing IPython Notebook cell

Tags: ipython, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

My **PyCharm** freezes after running any code in **.ipynb** (Jupyter Notebook) file.
i.e. the cell starts running and after that PyCharm doesnt respond and I have to kill it. No message is shown.

.py scripts are running correctly. Can anyone help?

My versions:

```
 PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3   (Ubuntu 16.04)
 ipython                   5.1.0                    py35_0  
 jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_3  
 notebook                  4.2.3                    py35_0
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your jupyter kernel is not running.

I have had success by first starting a jupyter notebook from the command line:

`$jupyter notebook`.

Then go back to the PyCharm jupyter notebook and run a cell. If you get the dialog box to enter the Jupyter Notebook URL, enter the url printed to your command line terminal session after you started the notebook there.